# Question about calculating sentiment scores for cells (paragraph-length) in a large df

Tags: r, dplyr, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a sentiment analysis project in `R`. I have a `df` with containing speeches given by legislators in the Russian parliament over the period 2004 to 2007. The nature of the data is such that any given individual legislator may speak multiple times in this period (e.g., a few speeches in 2004, none in 2005, dozens in 2006, etc.). Here is code to reproduce the first several rows of this `df`.

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, text = c("С учетом того, что это последний вопрос от фракции ЛДПР, прежде всего я хотел бы поблагодарить от имени большинства депутатов пришедших к нам генерального прокурора, директора Федеральной службы безопасности и министра внутренних дел. Поблагодарить именно за то, что, несмотря на то что мы им даем достаточно мало полномочий и недостаточно денег, личный состав их ведомств каждый день выполняет поставленные задачи. И никто не сомневается, что вы в состоянии их решить. А теперь вопрос министру внутренних дел: товарищ министр, какие меры принимаются для активизации деятельности по стабилизации ситуации в Чеченской Республике?", 
"Уважаемый Борис Вячеславович, уважаемые коллеги! Проектом федерального закона предусматривается внесение изменений и дополнений в статьи 188, 228-232 Уголовного кодекса, а также дополнение Уголовного кодекса новыми статьями 228-1, 228-2, вносятся уточнения в Уголовно-процессуальный кодекс Российской Федерации, определяющие подсудность и подследственность, и предлагается также новая редакция статьи 6.8 Кодекса Российской Федерации об административных правонарушениях. Авторами проекта закона являются двадцать шесть депутатов третьего и второго созывов, тринадцать депутатов из состава этой Государственной Думы, в том числе двенадцать из фракции \"Единая Россия\". Каждый из нас, работая со своими избирателями в регионах, в полной мере ощущает, что проблема, обсуждаемая сегодня, действительно существует. Удивление вызывает позиция Комитета по законодательству в Думе предыдущего созыва, который два года не выносил данный законопроект на рассмотрение, в то время как все заключения по нему были готовы еще два года назад. Понятно, что вопрос непростой и он требует детального обсуждения. Я думаю, что во многом оно было бы другим, если бы законопроект рассматривался два года назад. За эти два года проблема не уменьшилась. Я хотел бы процитировать последнее, недавнее, заключение комитета: \"По мнению комитета, концепция законопроекта заслуживает поддержки. В частности, большое практическое значение имеет дополнение статьи 228 Уголовного кодекса Российской Федерации примечанием, устанавливающим порядок определения размеров наркотических средств и психотропных веществ, обнаруженных в незаконном обороте. Законодательная неурегулированность данного вопроса является одной из основных проблем действующего уголовного закона\". Я это процитировал исключительно с одной целью: сказать о том, что не все проблемы решены, существует часть нерешенных проблем. Я не хочу особо вдаваться в подробности, потому что в пояснительной записке к закону довольно подробно описаны сами проблемы и пути решения ряда из них. Учитывая то, что Государственная Дума действительно приняла проект, внесенный Президентом Российской Федерации, законопроект в том виде, в котором он внесен, не может быть утвержден. Я согласен и с депутатом Ройзманом, и с депутатом Васильевым, которые сказали о том, что есть проблема и необходимо сконцентрировать внимание под эгидой одного из комитетов на комплексном решении этой проблемы. Действительно, это становится уже проблемой безопасности нашего общества и нашего народа и проблемой выживания народа и государства на данном историческом этапе. Я считаю, что в дальнейшем уже с учетом принятого президентом закона мы могли бы внести другие проекты законов, которые позволят учесть все рациональные зерна, имеющиеся во всех проектах, которые рассматривает сегодня Государственная Дума. Но хотел бы еще раз подчеркнуть, что все проблемы урегулирования на законодательном уровне вопросов распространения, сбыта, хранения и употребления наркотиков не решены. Спасибо за внимание.", 
"Уважаемый Борис Вячеславович, я просто хотел сказать, что 18-е - это суббота, и всё. Прошу просто обратить внимание.", 
"Уважаемый Борис Вячеславович, я просто хотел сказать, что 18-е - это суббота, и всё. Прошу просто обратить внимание.", 
"Уважаемая Любовь Константиновна, уважаемые депутаты! Я и Комитет Государственной Думы по собственности не видим оснований для снятия вопроса 14. В прошлый раз из-за неявки докладчика вопрос был перенесен, то есть зафиксирован факт неявки докладчика, перенесено рассмотрение вопроса на 25-е число. На Совете вопрос был перенесен на сегодняшний день. Оснований для снятия его нет. Я прошу предоставить право доложить о законопроекте и проголосовать по нему.", 
"Уважаемый Борис Вячеславович, уважаемые коллеги! Я прошу снять пункт 9 с повестки дня. Обоснование позже."
), year = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L), question = c("Об обеспечении безопасности в Российской Федерации в связи с произошедшими террористическими актами.", 
"О проекте федерального закона № 200542-3 \"О внесении изменений и дополнений в Уголовный кодекс Российской Федерации, Уголовно-процессуальный кодекс Российской Федерации и Кодекс Российской Федерации об административных правонарушениях\" (в части усиления ответственности за незаконный сбыт наркотических средств и психотропных веществ и вовлечение в их потребление, а также дифференциации ответственности за правонарушения, не связанные с их сбытом; внесен депутатами Государственной Думы В. А. Аверченко, А. Г. Аксаковым, А. Г. Баскаевым, А. Н. Белоусовым, В. П. Войтенко, В. В. Гальченко, Н. Ф. Герасименко, М. И. Гришанковым, А. С. Ивановым, Г. К. Леонтьевым, С. И. Колесниковым, С. Н. Шишкарёвым и В. В. Чайкой и депутатами Государственной Думы третьего созыва Н. А. Овчинниковым, В. П. Воротниковым, А. Е. Баранниковым, В. А. Буткеевым, А. Ю. Вульфом, Е. Г. Зяблицевым, В. Е. Коптевым-Дворниковым, О. Н. Коргуновым, А. Д. Куликовым, В. А. Певцовым, А. Г. Пузановским, В. О. Семёновым и И. М. Ханкоевым).", 
"О проекте порядка работы Государственной Думы на 31 июля 2004 года.", 
"О проекте постановления Государственной Думы \"О внесении изменений в постановление Государственной Думы Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации \"О внесении изменений в постановление Государственной Думы Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации \"О распорядке работы депутатов Государственной Думы на период с 12 января по 3 июля 2004 года (весенняя сессия)\" и о распорядке работы депутатов Государственной Думы на период с 11 июля по 17 сентября 2004 года (весенняя сессия)\".", 
"О проекте федерального закона № 9855-4 \"О внесении изменений в Федеральный закон \"О несостоятельности (банкротстве)\" (в части расширения полномочий органов исполнительной власти субъектов Российской Федерации, органов местного самоуправления в осуществлении процедуры банкротства).", 
"О проекте порядка работы Государственной Думы на 29 апреля 2004 года."
), deputy_id = c(99100002L, 99100703L, 99109965L, 99109965L, 
99109965L, 99109965L), name = c("Абельцев Сергей Николаевич", 
"Аверченко Владимир Александрович", 
"Агеев Александр Александрович", "Агеев Александр Александрович", 
"Агеев Александр Александрович", "Агеев Александр Александрович"
), party_id = c("LDPR", "UR", "UR", "UR", "UR", "UR"), question_stage = c("-", 
"Рассмотрение законопроекта в первом чтении", 
"-", "-", "Рассмотрение законопроекта в первом чтении", 
"-"), Date = c("2004-10-28", "2004-03-02", "2004-07-30", "2004-07-30", 
"2004-06-29", "2004-04-28")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**The main goal of my analysis is to calculate sentiment scores for each observation in the `text` column.** As can be seen in the example data provided, these are usually no more than ten to fifteen sentences long. Here is my coding procedure thus far:

```
# load the Russian sentiment dictionary
dict <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/text-machine-lab/sentimental/master/sentimental/word_list/russian.csv")

mydata <- newdata %>% # subset to relevant variables
  select(deputy_id, text) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text) # unnest tokens (output = word column, input = text)

# calculate sentiment scores for each word 
mydata_sentiment <- mydata %>% 
  inner_join(dict, by = "word")
```

Up to this point I have calculated sentiment scores for all words. This is fine. Now, the next step is to calculate the scores for each cell. My approach is as follows:

```
mydata <- mydata_sentiment %>% 
  group_by(deputy_id) %>% 
  summarise(sentiment = mean(score))
```

The problem is that takes the average of **all** scores associated with each `deputy_id`. Put differently, for all words linked to a particular `deputy_id`, the code takes the average of all of them and assigns them to that deputy. **I need sentiment scores for each cell of `text` associated with each `deputy_id`** Does anyone know how to do this? I would appreciate any advice, and please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of getting what you want. You can keep the texts or introduce a text_id. Both examples below.

To keep the texts, you can use `drop = FALSE` in `unnest_tokens`

using your code:

```
mydata <- newdata %>% # subset to relevant variables
  select(deputy_id, text) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text, drop = FALSE)
```

When you do this, next you can group by deputy_id and text.

```
mydata <- mydata_sentiment %>% 
  group_by(deputy_id, text) %>% 
  summarise(sentiment = mean(score))
```

Or you can introduce a text identifier so you don't need the whole text.

```
mydata <- newdata %>% # subset to relevant variables
  select(deputy_id, text) %>% 
  mutate(text_id = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text) 

mydata <- mydata_sentiment %>% 
  group_by(deputy_id, text_id) %>% 
  summarise(sentiment = mean(score))
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Shouldn't the number of observations in the `df` without the sentiment scores (47,755) be the same as the `df` with the scores (36,876), though?

Comment: Not really, you are doing an `inner_join` with the sentiment scores. So words that do not appear in the sentiment dictionary will be dropped. Hence lower observations. If you want to have all the observations, you need to use `left_join`, but then you have a lot of NA's in your data which do not serve any purpose.